# Are there any stories which are about a species that is neither human nor divine?

Tags: mythical-creatures, comparative

I am aware that some mythologies/religions include species apart from humans and gods (e.g. Islam and Norse mythology). However, are there any stories which are  written about them? My definition for "stories" for this questions, will be stories that are about individuals or groups seen as the protagonists, or heroes, of the stories.

Please note that I am *not* looking for origin stories of a particular species, nor stories about people who are (semi-)divine, like avatars of Hinduism  or demigods of Greco-Roman mythology.

Comment: Mahabharata does include other species. See Garudas, a race of bird people, descendants of [Garuda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garuda). Also [Nagas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%81ga) that are half human and half snake.

Comment: @Ishan Singh Firstly, there is only *1* Garuda and secondly, they are *not* the protagonists

Comment: No, there are many Garudas. Read further in the link I gave.

Comment: @Ishan Singh your link claims that Garuda fathered *birds* , not "Garudas".

Comment: Just to be clear, the creatures have to be the protagonists, thus "Arabian Nights" is not an answer b/c the Jinn are not the "hero" of the story? Also assuming Aesop's fables about animals are not what you're looking for?

Comment: Thing is, creatures like that, especially in religious mythologies, are always _antagonists_, an obstacle for the heroes to overcome, or something to scare children into eating more vegetables. Telling such stories from the "villain's" perspective is very much a modern idea that was I believe kickstarted by Disney.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo But creatures do/have not necessarily have to be seen in a negative light. The nymphs of Greek Mythology or the Alfar of Norse mythology were not villains, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention nymphs, so I'll direct you to [Daphne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daphne), who is the [heroine of her story](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Metamorphoses/Daphne_and_Apollo). It may start with Apollo, but he is distinctly the antagonist, thus, while the story *involves* him, it is *about* her. (I suspect Ovid's [Metamorphosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metamorphoses) will be fertile ground for you in your search.)

I am also going to propose [John Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Gardner_(American_writer))'s [Grendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grendel_(novel)), which may not be strictly canonical, but is certainly worthwhile and a part of the overall Beowulf body of literature.

(Also, technically, Sun Wukong is neither human nor a god, but a monkey born from a magical stone who gains power through Taoist training.)

Comment: I think calling John Gardner's novel "not strictly canonical" is somewhat generous. I would call it "not *remotely* canonical".

Comment: @femtoRgon :)  but it has led to some fertile ground in modern adaptations of Beowulf, and is within the greater canon of literature, if not mythology, strictly